# retrieve the rows of a column from a database table and sort every word of the row

Tags: java, jdbc

after applying sorting i am getting some sentences in sorted manners while in other sentences all the words are sorted but except first word.
eg-  Amako; Jun (Shiojiri, JP), Umetsu; Kazushige (Chino, JP), Tanaya; Hideo   (Suwa, JP)

Aoki; Shigenori (Kawasaki, JP), Kato; Masayuki (Kawasaki, JP)

De Dobbelaere; Peter (San Diego, CA), Pinguet; Thierry (Arlington, WA), Peterson; Mark (San Diego, CA), Harrison; Mark (Escondido, CA), Dickinson; Alexander G. (Laguna Beach, CA), Gunn, III; Lawrence C. (Encinitas, CA)

output is-  Hideo (Suwa, JP)     Jun (Shiojiri, JP), Umetsu     Kazushige (Chino, JP), Tanaya    Amako

Masayuki (Kawasaki, JP)     Shigenori (Kawasaki, JP), Kato    Aoki

Alexander G. (Laguna Beach, CA), Gunn, III     Lawrence C. (Encinitas, CA)     Mark (Escondido, CA), Dickinson     Mark (San Diego, CA), Harrison     Peter (San Diego, CA), Pinguet     Thierry (Arlington, WA), Peterson    De Dobbelaere

Code sample:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

while (rs.next()) {
    results.add(rs.getString(1));
}
for (int i = 1; i < results.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(results);
    ArrayList<String> newLines = new ArrayList<String>(results);

    for (String line : lines) {
        line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 2).trim();
        String[] words = line.split(";");
        Arrays.sort(words);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line.length());
        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.isEmpty())
                continue;
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append("    ");
            }
            sb.append(word);
        }
        String newLine = sb.toString();
        newLines.add(newLine);
    }

    System.out.println("sorted lines:");
    for (String line : newLines) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorting of the words in the row separated by ";"

Comment: Does this code compiles..

Comment: Please incorporate your comment's specification into the question.

Comment: yes it compiles and providing result but in proper form.

Comment: Its very simple 1. split each line `String@split("; ");` 2. use `Arrays#sort(-)` to sort it. Apply this to other lines.

Comment: your code doesn't make sense after I re-indent it.  Can you clean that up before you post instead of posting rubbish?

Comment: and, what are you showing as sample? Column names (as what you said)? or values of a specific column?

Comment: Thank you so much @AdrianShum  for your kind help.

Comment: No need to thank me, I haven't helped anything.  I just want to see a clear and understandable question.  Even that "updated" piece of code you posted as answer does not make sense.  Do you know what is indentation?  Can you indent your code to make sure it make sense?  ANd, a second look into the sample data you posted, I have no clues what you are trying to do.  Is that really that difficult to ask question in a way that people can understand easily?

Comment: In your code, you accumulate previous "results"  for each row you fetched from DB.  No way to tell the rationale behind that.  And, if you are storing more than 1 lines in each row in DB, consider properly normalize it and make it a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve it ordered by name in SQL.

```
SELECT firstName, lastName
FROM myTable
ORDER BY lastName ASC;
```

(or DESC, if you want Z to A)

Answer (score 0):

1. Split each line `String@split("; ")`
2. Use `Arrays#sort(-)` to sort it.

Ex:

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

//for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++){

String in = "Amako; Jun (Shiojiri, JP), Umetsu; Kazushige (Chino, JP)," 
             +"Tanaya; Hideo (Suwa, JP)  ,";
//in = (String)results.get(i);
in = in.substring(0, in.length()-2).trim();

String str[] = in.split("; ");//1

Arrays.sort(str);//2

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(String s:str)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append("; ");
    }


    System.out.println(sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-2));

    lines.add(sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-2));
//}
```

Output:

```
Amako; Hideo (Suwa, JP) ; Jun (Shiojiri, JP), Umetsu; Kazushige (Chino, JP), Tanaya
```

Do same thing for remaining lines..

Comment: Thank you Satya it is providing the output , But it is printing the output multiple times. I know there is a loop mistake but i am not able to catch it. Please help me.

Comment: _Printing the output multiple times_. Your issue in `while` loop. before the first `for` loop you should close the `while` loop. @prerna

Comment: No closing `while` before the first `for` loop will effect the result.. @prerna

Comment: It helps in reducing the number of iterations but still it is producing the repetitive results.

Comment: while(rs.next()) {
        results.add(rs.getString(1));
       }
       
       for (int i = 1; i < results.size(); i++)
       {

Comment: not as comment it should be in your question just edit it. but don't erase the previous one.

Comment: can you please help me that question please @ Satya